# AWS managed Grafana can not connect RDS Postgres DB as datasource with ssl enabled

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-rds, grafana

Grafna works fine with SSL disabled at RDS postgres configuration but when enabled Grafana start throwing below error.

```
db query error: pq: no pg_hba.conf entry for host <IP>, user "grafana", database "system_monitor", no encryption
```

I tried to find steps to configure Datasource connection with "TLS/SSL Mode" required.
But I am sure from where I should get "TLS/SSL Client Certificate" and "TLS/SSL Client Key"

Please point me to correct documentation or share steps to configure this.

Note: Grafana is service and not hosted on EC2.

Edit: Settings Grafana asking
[image]

TSL/SSL Method Options
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are links to download the RDS certificate bundles near the top of this page: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL.html

Comment: I believe the SSL mode values in the connection settings come from here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-ssl.html If that's true, then using a value of `require` would use SSL without validating the server certificate.

Comment: @MarkB I got that RDS certificate after adding that in setting it look for client key.
Error is "db query error: stat /var/lib/grafana/tls/wXRg6gtSzgeneratedTLSCerts/client.key: no such file or directory"

Comment: There shouldn't be a client key, since this isn't Mutual TLS, you aren't supposed to be sending a key from your side. What do you have selected for "TLS/SSL Method"?

Comment: Yes, I left "TSL/SSL Client Key" empty. 
TLS/SSL Method as "Certificate Content" and I copy-pasted certificate content from certificate bundle.

Comment: I don't think "Certificate Content" is the correct setting, but I don't use Grafana, I just know about general SSL connections to Postgres, so I'm not sure what to tell you to select there without being able to see what the options are.

Comment: I think its option either provide certs & key by content or file path (Picture added in question desc). Also file path is relevant in case of Grafana hosted on EC2 and you have access to EC2 filesystem to store certs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLS secure config (not ignoring TLS cert verification): You need to configure `TLS/SSL Root Certificate`, where you need to paste PEM root CA, which you can download from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL.html#UsingWithRDS.SSL.RegionCertificates  (don't be tempted to use `Certificate bundles for all AWS Regions` - they are huge and may brick your Grafana, just use smaller region specific CA certs).

You need to end up with this kind of config:
[image]